# valid JSON response issue

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, response

I have published my app on android, and now I'm facing a problem with the JSON response on some devices ?!
[image: screen shot showing the error which says no connection]

Comment: Please add some relevant code, and stacktrace..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error message is telling you that some servers don't return valid JSON (or at least returning something that your code/library cannot handle). You might want to add some error checking code that would address such conditions.